# zip excludes certain js files for no apparent reason

Tags: files, osx, zip, node.js

Trying to build a zip package for AWS Lambda that runs a node app. I'm using OSX `zip` to package the lambda bundle like this:

`zip -dg -q -FS -R function.zip index.js "*.json" node_modules`

However, for some reason, the resulting zip file excludes the files under `src` folder as highlighted in the screenshot. It includes "only 2" files from `core` subfolder which makes this thing very strange.

I'm not too familiar with `zip` and the man pages don't point out anything odd that I might be doing.

Any idea what I'm missing?

[image]

Here's the resulting zip file

[image]

Comment: @Jesse_b I uploaded the resulting zip file's structure. I didn't realize until now but `core` seems weirder (it doesn't have `lint.js`).

Comment: Oh, so those args are acting like patterns instead of actual filenames? You might be on to something.

Comment: Yep, that was it! This works `zip -dg -q -FS -R function.zip \"*.js\" node_modules/* \"*.json\"`. It may not be the final thing I want but this points me in the right direction. Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: That `*.json` pattern should in any case be `"*.json"` or `'*.json'`, without escaping the quotes.

Comment: @Kusalananda You're right. I copy/pasted my npm script from `package.json` which is `"build": "rm -rf function.zip && zip -dg -q -FS -R function.zip \"*.js\" \"*.json\" ",` - hence the need for escaping.

Comment: If you had used single quotes for the patterns, they would not needed that those backslashes.

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah but single quotes don't expand, do they?

Comment: Globs don't expand in double quotes either. In this case, you want to pass the _pattern_ to `zip`, not the expansion of it.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how messed up my understanding of the command was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the zip man page for the -R option it states the following:

```
   -R
   --recurse-patterns
          Travel the directory structure recursively starting at the current directory; for example:

                 zip -R foo "*.c"

          In this case, all the files matching *.c in the tree starting at the current directory are stored into a zip archive named foo.zip.  Note that *.c  will
          match file.c, a/file.c and a/b/.c.  More than one pattern can be listed as separate arguments.  Note for PKZIP users: the equivalent command is
```

So it is searching the directory tree for `index.js`, `\"*.json\"` (honestly not sure how it's handling that pattern or what you are trying to accomplish with it), and `node_modules`.  However you have not specified `"*.js"` or anything similar to include the other .js files.

Comment: Yeah, I read that option wrong. I basically want my js, json files, and ***anything*** under `node_modules`.